# How an ext4 disk became suddenly write protected in spite configuration is read/write?

Tags: linux, rhel, mount, fstab, disk

We have a Redhat 7 machine. And the filesystem for device `/dev/sdc` is ext4.

When we perform:

```
mount -o rw,remount /grop/sdc
```

We get write protected error like:

```
/dev/sdc read-write, is write-protected
```

in spite the `/etc/fstab` allow read and write and all sub folder under `/grop/sdc` have full write/read permissions:

```
/dev/sdc /grop/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

Then we do

```
umount -l  /grop/sdc
```

and from `df -h`, we see that the disk is currently not mounted.

Then we perform

```
 mount /grop/sdc
```

but we get busy. :-(

So we do not have a choice and we perform a reboot.

And from history we do not see that someone limited the disk for read only by mount.

This is very strange, how the disk device became write protected?

In order to solve this we perform a full reboot, and now the disk is *write/read* as it should be.

What happens here, after reboot we check the dmesg and we see the following:

```
 EXT4-fs warning (device sdc): ext4_clear_journal_err:4698: Marking fs in need of filesystem check.
 EXT4-fs (sdc): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
 EXT4-fs (sdc): recovery complete
```

*can we say that during boot - e2fsck was performed ?*

```
dmesg | grep sdc
[sdc] Disabling DIF Type 2 protection
[sdc] 15628053168 512-byte logical blocks: (8.00 TB/7.27 TiB)
[sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[sdc] Write Protect is off
[sdc] Mode Sense: d7 00 10 08
[sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
sdc: unknown partition table
[sdc] Attached SCSI disk
EXT4-fs warning (device sdc): ext4_clear_journal_err:4697: Filesystem error 
 recorded from previous mount: IO failure
EXT4-fs warning (device sdc): ext4_clear_journal_err:4698: Marking fs in 
need of filesystem check.
EXT4-fs (sdc): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
 EXT4-fs (sdc): recovery complete
 EXT4-fs (sdc): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
 EXT4-fs (sdc): error count since last fsck: 5
 EXT4-fs (sdc): initial error at time 1510277668: ext4_journal_check_start:56
 EXT4-fs (sdc): last error at time 1510496990: ext4_put_super:791
```

Comment: Very unclear question. What makes you think that "we get write protected"? Show the command (or output, or log) which shows that. Maybe use [lsof(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html). Show relevant lines in output of `mount` (without arguments). So you need to work more on your question, so **edit your question** to improve it more.

Comment: Show also the permissions (with `ls -ld` or `stat`) of `/grop/sdc` before and after `mount` commands.

Comment: Did you carefully read the documentation of [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html), [mount(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html)? What file system are you using? What `file -s /dev/sdc` gives before any mount? Read [e2fsck(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/e2fsck.8.html). Did you try (before the mount) some `e2fsck -v /dev/sdc` ? What did you got from that?

Comment: hi Basile , not have the output because not save the screen memory but its for sure said that write protected !  when we run the remount , second the ds is ext4 , and under the folder ( by ls 0ld ) we have write permissions ,

Comment: If you don't edit your question you won't get valid answers. Youn don't need any screenshot, you can (and should) use commands and give their outputs (or lines in log files) in textual form (indented lines, four spaces before each of them). BTW Linux has directories, not folders (and terminology is important)

Comment: ok not problem -  I will update the question

Comment: Even with the updates, the question remains unclear. Perhaps your hardware is broken.... Prepare yourself for some data loss (you do have backups elsewhere). Try to `umount`, then `e2fsck`, then `mount`. [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) utilities like `smartctl` might be helpful.

Comment: what you mean HW is broken , after reboot sdc is mounted without problem so how it can be HW is broken?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68606/discussion-between-yael-and-basile-starynkevitch).

Comment: Have you looked at the system log yet?

Comment: yes see my update question on the last lines ,

Comment: any consultations after my update ?

Comment: Is `/dev/sdc read-write, is write-protected` really the exact error message? Or is it more like `mount: /grop/sdc: /dev/sdc is write-protected but explicit read-write`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears your filesystem has become corrupt somehow. Most filesystems switch to read-only mode once they encounter an error. Please perform the following commands in a terminal:

```
umount /dev/sdc
e2fsck /dev/sdc
mount /dev/sdc
```

If /dev/sdc is the harddisk which has your operating system on it, use a startup DVD or usb stick to boot from.

Comment: BTW, I recommend doing a backup. I'm guessing that the hard disk is dying.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The dmesg doesn't say block-level problems on the disk, although the OP gave us only a filtered one.

Comment: But failing `e2fsck` smells bad, especially when the failure repeats. And an extra backup is less costly than losing the content on an entire disk.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error most likely is in the past.
You should inspect system logs for messages related to the block device being used.
Recent tools (e.g. `dumpe2fs`) can even display when an error had occurred, like this:

```text
dumpe2fs 1.43.8 (1-Jan-2018)
Filesystem state: clean with errors
Errors behavior: Continue
FS Error count: 5
First error time: Mon Nov 1 00:22:11 2021
First error function: ext4_journal_check_start
First error line #: 60
First error inode #: 0
First error block #: 0
Last error time: Tue Nov 2 10:45:47 2021
Last error function: ext4_remount
Last error line #: 5175
Last error inode #: 0
Last error block #: 0
```

So that time stamps will give you a good interval where to look in the logs.

(For the case shown it was a loop mount of a sparse file and the underlying container filesystem was full)