# How to resolve e2fsck Superblock problem?

Tags: fstab, e2fsck, ufs

I have a problem like this question
[How disk became suddenly write protected in spite configuration is read/write?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404019/how-disk-became-suddenly-write-protected-in-spite-configuration-is-read-write)

And I used these commands to resolve that

`umount /dev/sdb1
e2fsck /dev/sdb1
mount /dev/sdb1`

but

```
~# e2fsck /dev/sdb1
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

/dev/sdb1 contains a ufs file system
```

additional commands to help you to know additional details

```
~#nano /etc/fstab
UUID=###951671### /DATA ufs defaults 1 2

mkdir /DATA

mount /DATA

~# ls -lat | grep DATA
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root     1024 May 26 11:37 DATA

~# df -h | grep sd
/dev/sda1       276G  8.7G  254G   4% /
**/dev/sdb1       197G  102G   80G  57% /DATA**

~# lsblk -f | grep sd
sda                                                                                      
├─sda1 ext4                          ###-c0fb-42ce-9c78-###  253.2G     3% /
├─sda2                                                                                   
└─sda5 swap                          ###-27b4-485b-98b3-###                [SWAP]
sdb                                                                                      
└─sdb1 ufs                           ###951671###                       79.3G    52% /DATA

~:/DATA# ls
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error


~:/DATA# mount -o rw,remount /dev/sdb1
mount: /DATA: mount point not mounted or bad option.

~# umount /DATA
~# e2fsck /DATA
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
e2fsck: Is a directory while trying to open /DATA

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

~# mount /DATA
mount: /DATA: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.
```

At all, I would like to access to this hard /dev/sdb1 in /DATA folder

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem

```
$ dmesg|grep bsd
```

[    3.467958]  sda1:

Then:

```
$ sudo mount -t ufs -r -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdb1 ~/freebsd
```

Of course, for another version of linux line ubuntu we need to know:
Possible common types are:

```
old old format of ufs
default value, supported as read-only
44bsd used in FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD
ufs2 used in FreeBSD 5.x
5xbsd synonym for ufs2
sun used in SunOS (Solaris)
sunx86 used in SunOS for Intel (Solarisx86)
hp used in HP-UX
nextstep used in NextStep
nextstep-cd used for NextStep CDROMs (block_size == 2048)
openstep used in OpenStep
```

and we have to use this command for ubuntu and like that

```
$ sudo mount -t ufs -r -o ufstype=44bsd /dev/sdb1 /DATA
```

Answer (score 5):

**Stop.**

According to `e2fsck`, your `/etc/fstab` file, and your `lsblk` output, the filesystem type on `/dev/sdb1` is `ufs`.

`e2fsck` is **only** for filesystem types `ext2`, `ext3` and `ext4`. It cannot fix filesystem type `ufs` at all, and may in fact cause more damage to an UFS filesystem if you force it to attempt repairs anyway.

For checking and fixing an UFS filesystem, you would need `fsck.ufs` instead. On some Linux distributions, it is available as a package named `ufsutils`: use your package manager to install it.

Other than that, UFS is not a very often used filesystem in Linux - it is more of a Solaris or *BSD thing, I think. If this disk was moved from a Solaris or BSD system, you might take it back there and use the tools of the original system to check the filesystem - those tools are much more likely to be up to date with the filesystem version actually used.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to uninstall or update ext2fsd in your Windows.
However, in order to bring your Linux back temporarily or urgently, you may write the command below in the black screen you see the error:

```
e2fscl -c <-y> <device>
```

where you may write your Linux partition instead of `<device>`; for instance, `/dev/sdb7`.
you either add `-y` or press <kbd>y</kbd> whenever the running asks you for it.

Comment: As the original question and the answer posted by the OP indicates, the filesystem type was `ufs`. That filesystem type is not compatible with the `e2fsck` or any other tools designed for ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems.