# Superblock problem on a crypto_LUKS drive

Tags: linux, fsck, superblock, e2fsck, whole-drive-encryption

When I try to boot from my main drive, I get this error:

[image]

That message says "Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found" so I tried this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/651577/dev-sda1-inodes-that-were-part-of-a-corrupted-orphan-linked-list-found - and got:

```
:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sda5 
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck: fsck.crypto_LUKS: not found
fsck: error 2 while executing fsck.crypto_LUKS for /dev/sda5
```

My problem seems similar to this - [How to resolve e2fsck Superblock problem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546712/how-to-resolve-e2fsck-superblock-problem) - except that solution doesn't work for me.

When I try that solution (running on a secondary drive) :

```
:~$ sudo e2fsck -b 163840 /dev/sda5
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
e2fsck: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sda1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

/dev/sda5 contains a crypto_LUKS file system
```

I'm not 100% sure the drive being encrypted is the causal reason that solution isn't working; maybe it's just not. But what other approaches can I take to solve this?

Let me know if there's any more information I can provide.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Please transcribe the text in to pure text--The glare from the photo combined with my display makes the photo unreadable for me.

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem on your root logical volume is corrupted, not the LUKS device itself. `/dev/sda5` is partition that holds the LUKS/dm-crypt device, with encryption (and also LVM which you are also using), the storage works in layers, you can't run `fsck` on the LUKS (encryption) layer, you must run it on the LVM logical volume layer -- `/dev/mapper/trisquel--vg-root` in your case.

If you are running this from the initramfs where the LUKS device is already unlocked (you provided passphrase earlier), you need to run `fsck /dev/mapper/trisquel--vg-root`. If you are running this from a LiveCD, you need to first manually unlock your encrypted drive (you can do that simply from the GUI by double clicking on the encrypted drive, or manually using [cryptsetup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption#Unlocking/Mapping_LUKS_partitions_with_the_device_mapper)) and then run the same `fsck /dev/mapper/trisquel--vg-root` command.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fsck the wrong thing.  Fsck thinks that partition is LUKS encrypted. Looking at the photo you also appear to be using LVM.

So I guess you have an LVM physical volume encrypted with LUKS.

The photo shows you've been dropped into an emergency shell.  I suspect when that happens, the encrypted drive has been unlocked and the volume group (and logical volume) have already been mapped...

... so you should be able to fsck the logical volume from the emergency shell:

```
fsck /dev/mapper/trisquel--vg-root
```